# Why is my else statement constantly recurring the print statement?

Tags: python, while-loop

I'm new to Python and Stack Overflow so please bear with me. I'm creating a 'guess the number' game. When the program offers the user a hint the user should either enter 'y' or 'n' as indicated:
`hint_option = str(input('Incorrect! Do you want a hint? (Y/N): ')).lower()`
otherwise, if another letter (e.g.) is entered I want the program to print `Invalid input! Please try again`

```
hint_loop = False
while hint_loop != True:
    if hint_option == 'y':
        if user_guess > random_num:
            hint = 'too high'
        else:
            hint = 'too low'
        print(f'''Hint: Your guess was {hint}
        ''')
        total_hints += 1
        break
    elif hint_option == 'n':
        break
    else:
        print('Invalid input! Please try again')
```

I don't know what to do, could someone please help me?

Comment: Could you please edit your comment to include what is currently going wrong?

Comment: Why do you need a `while` loop for giving the hint? An `if...else` statement is enough. And what _is_ the error? The only thing I can see is an infinite loop when the `else` block is triggered. You can rectify it using a `break` statement.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] rather than just a fragment which contains references to variables which are defined elsewhere.